# Multipage quick report needs to pull paper from different trays using Delphi

Tags: delphi

When printing a multipage quick report, is it possible to print a certain pages from one tray and the remaining pages pull from another?

Example:

In a 50 page quick report, the page numbers 1,5,7,13,17.. should pull the paper from page source(tray) 1 and the remaining pages should pull from page source 2.

Can you please let me know how this can be done using quick report.

I have been analyzing this for the past one week. So far from my analysis, i have found the below link with the same question asked in Quick report discussion forum  [Quickreport discussion forum](http://forum.quickreport.co.uk/default.aspx?g=posts&t=63)

I have tried this example on "Onstartpage event", but it is printing only blank pages.  I am not sure how to assign the quickreport canvas to delphi tprinter canvas for each page.

I am using Delphi XE3 and Quick report 5.